# Generate Code with redirection IntelliJ Idea 15

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-generation, intellij-15

I have a class like this:

```
public class BukkitPlayerWrapper implements Player {
    private Player p;

    public BukkitPlayerWrapper(Player p) {
        this.p = p;
    }
}
```

But Player interface has a lot of methods, is there a way in intelliJ to generate code like this?

```
@Override
public String getDisplayName() {
    return p.getDisplayName();
}

@Override
public void setDisplayName(String s) {
    p.setDisplayName(s);
}
```

Because writing it by hand will take hours.

Comment: Alt+Insert maybe? Not sure if it will work for inherited values though.

Comment: I endedup writing a program for it, but the question still stands how to do it in intelliJ I saw something with delegations but it doesn't want to generate the methods.

Comment: Why do you need to create an instance of the `Player` object from within its implementation, if I may ask?

Comment: Like @BrandonLaidig mentiond you should be able to do `Alt+Insert` and then select `Delegate Method...` and then the the member varaible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that's what you're looking for but if you have an interface e.g.

```
public interface ExampleInterface {

    void method1();

    void method2();
}
```

and you create a class that implements the interface and has a member variable:

```
public class SomeClass implements ExampleInterface {
    public ExampleInterface exampleInterface;

}
```

you can place the caret somewhere inside the class and hit `Alt`+`Insert` and it should give you this context menu:

[image: context menu]
then you click on `Delegate Methods...` and you'll get this:

[image: context menu 2]
select the the target member variable

[image]
and finally the methods you want to delegate and you'll end up with something similar to this:

```
public class SomeClass implements ExampleInterface {
    public ExampleInterface exampleInterface;

    @Override
    public void method1() {
        exampleInterface.method1();
    }

    @Override
    public void method2() {
        exampleInterface.method2();
    }
}
```

hope this helped a bit (: